# Rails link_to :confirm for a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and would like to know that, if there is a way to strict link_to :confirm for a specific page. Because I'm putting this in every page, but I don't want it to show a confirm message in every page.

I'm adding the code here as well, but the formate it's incorrect in the textbox.

```
link_to "Home",'/', :confirm => 'Clicking OK Will Discard Any Unsaved Changes. Click Cancel To Return To The Home Page.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a helper like this to restrict by controller_name and action:

```
def link_home(link_options = {})

  unless controller_name.eql?('some_controller') and action_name.eql?('some_action')
    link_options.merge!{:confirm => 'Clicking OK Will Discard Any Unsaved Changes. Click Cancel To Return To The Home Page.'}
  end


  link_to "Home",'/', link_options 

end
```

Comment: This could also be rewritten without adding indirection by using a block with Rails' built-in `link_to_if`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if